# Android - Getting identifier for view using string variable

Tags: java, android, view

I have a string variable which is the same as the identifier for a view.

I would like to use the R.id.xxx, but obviously I can't just replace the xxx with my string as the xxx is actually an int. What can I do to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s=getString(R.string.xxx);
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't quite what I meant. I am trying to retrieve a handle to a LinearLayout. Usually I  would use findViewById(R.id.idname). I have idname as a string - how can I use the findViewById method as this takes an int?

Comment: can you post your xml?what is there and what you want from there

Comment: In my xml there is
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/t112" android:padding="3dip"></LinearLayout>

and I have a string variable: String str = "t112"

I want to use this variable to retrieve a handle to the view it is the id of

Comment: Sounds like you want to replace a variable name.This is not possible

Comment: findViewById() takes integer as parameter and the integer parameter is determined by android system.How you can refer with other variable

Answer (score 1):

Nonsense. The framework obviously discourages that approach but it *is* possible: just use Java reflection, e.g.,

```
 java.lang.reflect.Field f = R.id.class.getField(name);
 int id = f == null ? -1 : (Integer)f.get(null);
 // now just use findViewById(id);
```